# while loop not working properly

Tags: bash

Coming from a Python background, I'm now learning Bash scripting. I am having a bit of trouble with a while loop. While trying to create a simple script that creates a new directory, the output behaves erratically.

In my first attempt using the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
        echo 'Enter directory name:'
        read newdir
        `mkdir $newdir`

        echo "[+] Directory created!"
        break

        if [ -d $newdir ];then
        echo "[-] cannot create directory. $newdir already exists."
        fi
done
```

The output is correct:

```
xuser@xuser-VB:~/Scripts$ ./newdir.sh
Enter directory name:
abc
[+] Directory created!
```

However, if I try to create a directory with the same name, it still outputs the `[+] Directory created!` on top of the system error message.

```
xuser@xuser-VB:~/Scripts$ ./newdir.sh
Enter directory name:
abc
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: File exists
[+] Directory created!
```

what am I missing or forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the existence of the directory **before** creating it.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
        echo 'Enter directory name:'
        read newdir

        if [ -d "$newdir" ] ; then
            echo "[-] cannot create directory. $newdir already exists."
            continue
        fi

        mkdir -- "$newdir"
        echo "[+] Directory created!"
        break
done
```

I also removed the backquotes, `mkdir` doesn't output anything, so they aren't useful in this context.

Moreover, double quote variables - without double quotes, directory names containing spaces would not work.

Using `mkdir -- "$newdir"` will interpret the $newdir as the directory name even if it starts with a dash.

Comment: That was a stoopid mistake. Thank you! :)

Comment: It might still be a good idea to check the mkdir exit status (something like  `mkdir -- "$newdir" && echo "[+] Directory created!"` perhaps) since it could fail for other reasons (read only filesystem, not enough inodes etc.)